# Is Evernote a good task management system?

Tags: evernote

Someone recently recommended [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) and I wanted to see if anyone has an opinion on this software as their main task management system.  It seems like it might be overkill

Comment: If you think it's overkill, than what are you looking for? And what are the requirements for qualifying as a good system?

Comment: -1 Subjective question that asks for opinion, rather than a specific answer.

Answer (score 4):

Having been an Evernote user for the last year or so, I'd say it can be (almost) whatever you want it to be.

I use it for recording notes, snippets, bookmarks and yes, todo lists. Use the 'insert checkbox' option (ctrl+shift+c) and there you go, an instant todo list. Coupled with notebooks and tags it's pretty flexible.

Each to their own 'n all that, but it works well as a task manager for me.

Answer (score 3):

Evernote is not a task management system, it's a document archiving solution (with features to sort, tag and annotate documents).

If you're looking for a task management solution, I suggest you check [**Remember The Milk**](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/).